# Ansible: Convert string to dictionary

Tags: ansible

I'm launching Ansible from Tower, then I'm filling the new users as a text:

```
{ name: user1, uid: 5000 }
{ name: user2, uid: 5001 }
```

I would like to iterate those users as a dictionary, something as:

```
- name: Print vars
  debug:
    var: "{{ item.name }}"
  with_items: "{{ users.split('\n') }}"
```

But it doesn't work:

```
TASK [Print vars] *********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [lx-test] => (item={ name: user1, uid: 5000 }) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "{ name: user1, uid: 5000 }",
    "{ name: user1, uid: 5000 }": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
ok: [lx-test] => (item={ name: user2, uid: 5001 }) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "{ name: user2, uid: 5001 }",
    "{ name: user2, uid: 5001 }": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}
```

Any idea how to convert that string to a real dictionary? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

The expression below

```yaml
users_list: "{{ users_str.splitlines()|map('from_yaml')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
users_list:
  - name: user1
    uid: 5000
  - name: user2
    uid: 5001
```

Declare the variable as [appropriate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    users_str: |
      {name: user1, uid: 5000}
      {name: user2, uid: 5001}

    users_list: "{{ users_str.splitlines()|map('from_yaml')|list }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: users_list
```

---

Optionally, put the data into a CSV file

```
shell> cat /tmp/users.csv 
name,uid
user1,5000
user2,5001
```

and use *community.general.read_csv* to read it

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - community.general.read_csv:
        path: /tmp/users.csv
      register: users
    - debug:
        var: users.list
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  users.list:
  - name: user1
    uid: '5000'
  - name: user2
    uid: '5001'
```

---

**Original answer**

The text is neither valid JSON nor YAML. You'll have to split the lines and read the dictionaries line by line. For example, given the text

```yaml
users_str: |
  {name: user1, uid: 5000}
  {name: user2, uid: 5001}
```

the task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        users_list: "{{ users_list|d([]) + [item|from_yaml] }}"
      loop: "{{ users_str.splitlines() }}"
```

creates the list of dictionaries

```yaml
users_list:
  - name: user1
    uid: 5000
  - name: user2
    uid: 5001
```

The iteration is trivial now

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: item.name
      loop: "{{ users_list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  item.name: user1
  item.name: user2
```

Comment: Thanks! your solutions worked awesome. But would you please explain what users_list: "{{ users_list|d([]) + [item|from_yaml] }}" does? Thanks!

Comment: Sure. The expression concatenates the list. 'd' is an alias of 'default'. The 'item' is a string therefore it must be converted by the filter 'from_yaml'. You might want to decompose the loop and see it on your own.

Comment: See the simplified code.